# React router v4 not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React and trying to follow a tutorial on how to set up the router. However when I run the app, the component does not render, and the HTML just says react-empty.

index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <Router>
   <App />
 </Router>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js:

```
const App = () => (
 <div>
  <Main />
 </div>
)

export default App;
```

Main.js:

```
const Main = () => (
  <div>  
     <main>
        <h1>MAIN</h1>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    </main>
  </div>
)

export default Main;
```

Home.js:

```
class Home extends Component {

constructor() {
    super()
    console.log('home component');
}

render() {
    return (

        <div>
            <h1 className="wat">waaaat</h1>
        </div>
        )
  }
}


export default Home;
```

Also, I can see the Route in the React plugin for chrome like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylscl.jpg

**EDIT:**

It works if i put:

```
 <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
 </Switch>
```

directly in App.js instead of the Main element.

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console? Also what is the lowercase main tag in your Main component?

Comment: No errors in the console, the lowercase main tag is from the tutorial, it doesn't make a difference if i remove it.

Comment: is there a way for you to check if you have the same version of webpack as your tutorial?

Comment: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/468 you may find this useful.

Comment: I used create-react-app to generate the project, it's using webpack version: 1.14.0, not sure I have the same problem as those people in the other thread though. My app renders, it's just the Route components not rendering.

Comment: can you please show your package.json file? I have one more hunch :)

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/13d7MeFg :-)